# knockout Validation - passing parameter from server side

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, knockout-validation, knockout-mvc

I am working with knockout in MVC application. I am using knockout validation for validating the input. Everything is just fine,my problem is,I have a range validator for that input ll be coming from server view model.

how can I make that as my range validators minimum and maximum validation criteria?

since I am having all my code in separate js file I cant use @ attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your code set up, you *can* use the `@` attribute (Razor code) as you said. Simply set a local variable on the page, then run your code that's in the external file, like this, where in your external js file, you can access `min` and `max`.

```
@* This is your razor .cshtml page *@

<script type="text/javascript">

var min = @ViewBag.Min;
var max = @ViewBag.Max;

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/your-external-js"/>
```

Or, to keep things clean, you could use an initialize function:

```
@* This is your razor .cshtml page *@

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/your-external-js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var min = @ViewBag.Min;
    var max = @ViewBag.Max;
    myExternalJs.Initialize(min, max);
});

</script>
```